# Is this question about if-statements really an off-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, on-hold

I would like to ask whether the following question is really an off-topic:

[How to condense my 9 if statements into one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50107150/how-to-condense-my-9-if-statements-into-one/50118997)

---

I'm confused, because there is a plenty amount of similar questions, which are valid:

[Refactoring if/else logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913495/refactoring-if-else-logic)

[How to use Java 8 Optionals, performing an action if all three are present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48446622/how-to-use-java-8-optionals-performing-an-action-if-all-three-are-present/48446865)

[Replacing if else statement with pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28049094/replacing-if-else-statement-with-pattern)

[Replacing If Statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28460452/replacing-if-statements)

Personally, I'm a little bit disappointed that this question was put on a hold... After 22 hours of been alive...

Comment: I've reopened it, just to indicate that it really is on-topic.  However, note that you did already receive several very good answers to your question, so there really wasn't any *compelling* reason to reopen it.  Also, note that Stack Overflow *isn't a discussion forum.*

Comment: So that question blew up more than I had thought it ever could...

Comment: @RobertHarvey:  Yeah, I was there kinda early looking at it.  Definitely didn't seem like it was a *bad* question, but now I understand that the bike shed is going to have a vending machine with sparkling water...

Comment: @Robert Thanks! Certainly, I agree with you, and would like to add that I also don't see any compelling reason in putting this question on-hold...

Comment: Just make sure you're clear about your own motivations.  If your goal was to get an answer to your question, that goal was satisfied admirably, even though the question got closed.  if your goal was to solicit an ongoing discussion, well, we don't do that here.

Comment: @Robert I just wanted to understand the line between *off-topic* and *on-topic* for myself. Also, in such a case, we can close any well-answered question, but we don't do that, right? We strive to be **welcoming** and that was my motivation... **P.S.** Original question isn't mine.

Comment: `Also, in such a case, we can close any well-answered question, but we don't do that, right?` -- We do, if the question is clearly off-topic.